# Почему не прокручивается div с картинкой на заднем фоне?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть `div` на странице, в теге `<header>`, на котором отображается изображение (фон), две надписи и кнопка.

```
<header>
      <div class="main-section">
        <h1 class="main-label main-color">Welcome To The Beach!</h1>
        <p class="secondary-font main-color">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero,
          inventore ipsum quis accusamus placeat veritatis.
        </p>
        <button class="btn main-color secondary-font">Read More!</button>
      </div>
 </header>
```

Этот div привязан к css-классу `.main-section`, вот его содержимое:

```
.main-section {
    background-image: url("../img/beachshowcase.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /* background-size: cover; - не работает =((( */
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Все отображается так, как я и хочу.

Но далее, в теге `<main>` я хочу разместить еще один `<div>` с основной информацией. Сделал это:

```
<main>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi
    blanditiis sed eveniet quae, dolores aliquam eius praesentium minima
    doloremque atque nobis animi velit nulla dolore? Impedit quo fugit
    voluptatum perferendis.
  </div>
</main>
```

Проблема возникает на этом моменте: я просто не вижу `<div>`, который в теге `<main>`. Я и хотел этого, но ожидал, что появиться полоса прокрутки, с помощью которой можно бы было прокрутиться к основной информации - но она не появляется.

Как исправить эту проблему?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-section {
  background-image: url("../img/beachshowcase.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* background-size: cover; - не работает =((( */
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-color {
  --color: #926239;
  color: var(--color);
}

.main-label {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
  margin-top: 17.5%;
}

.secondary-font {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 10%;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: var(--color);
  border-width: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/styles.css" />
  <title>Freshcode - Main Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="main-section">
      <h1 class="main-label main-color">Welcome To The Beach!</h1>
      <p class="secondary-font main-color">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, inventore ipsum quis accusamus placeat veritatis.
      </p>
      <button class="btn main-color secondary-font">Read More!</button>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi blanditiis sed eveniet quae, dolores aliquam eius praesentium minima doloremque atque nobis animi velit nulla dolore? Impedit quo fugit voluptatum perferendis.
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Как это отображается у меня в браузере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот здесь проблема:
`<div>`, который я вставил в теге  - его не видно. Судя по всему, он встал в самом начале страницы, а мне нужно чтобы он был внизу, как показано на этом [сайте](https://jolly-kalam-23776e.netlify.app/fullscreenlanding/).

Comment: Какая структура в которой находится `main`? Наиболее быстрый способ вам помочь это когда будет оформлен рабочий пример, `html` и `css` добавьте через `Фрагмент кода на JavaScript/HTML/CSS Ctrl-M`

Comment: @klifort, вроде добавил то, о чем Вы попросили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переделал ваш код.
Поведение блока `main` было через то что у вас на `.main-section` есть `position:fixed;`

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header {
   background-image: url('http://traversymedia.com/downloads/assets/beachshowcase.jpg');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-position: center;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   text-align: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }

.main-color {
   --color: #926239;
color: var(--color);
}
.main-label {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 0%;
}
.secondary-font {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.btn {
   margin-top: 1.5%;
   padding: 1%;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 200px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-color: var(--color);
   border-width: 0.5px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="main-section">
   <h1 class="main-label main-color">Welcome To The Beach!</h1>
   <p class="secondary-font main-color">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, inventore ipsum quis accusamus placeat veritatis.
   </p>
   <button class="btn main-color secondary-font">Read More!</button>
</div>
 </header>
 <main>
   <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi blanditiis sed eveniet quae, dolores aliquam eius praesentium minima doloremque atque nobis animi velit nulla dolore? Impedit quo fugit voluptatum perferendis.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi blanditiis sed eveniet quae, dolores aliquam eius praesentium minima doloremque atque nobis animi velit nulla dolore? Impedit quo fugit voluptatum perferendis.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi blanditiis sed eveniet quae, dolores aliquam eius praesentium minima doloremque atque nobis animi velit nulla dolore? Impedit quo fugit voluptatum perferendis.
   </div>
 </main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо)
Отметил Ваш ответ)